Not able to add 3 div element in same row in css
i have a html and css file i am creating a nav bar structure i created 3 div and assign them width of 20vw, 50vw, 30vw respectively and set those div display property inline-block but the problem is those div are not rendering in same line
Html Code


  * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-bar {
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  .nav-bar-column1 {
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 30px;
    width: 20vw;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .nav-bar-column2 {
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 30px;
    width: 50vw;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .nav-bar-column3 {
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30vw;
    display: inline-block;
  }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="nav-bar">
      <div class="nav-bar-columns">
        <div class="nav-bar-column1">
          Logo
        </div>
        <div class="nav-bar-column2">
          Search Bar
        </div>
        <div class="nav-bar-column3">
          Whishlist Cart Account
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <body>

  </body>
  <footer>

  </footer>
</body>

</html>




I made a snippet of your code and formatted it which more clearly shows the HTML of malformed/invalid as posted

20 + 50 + 30 + borders exceeds 100 here even if it were properly formed

how to solve this problem can you please tell me

One idea would be to utilize box-sizing: border-box; - see MDN docs: border-box. Feel free to check out CSS properties you're not familiar with on that site.


Update with valid HTML.  2 Update CSS to be valid and not be malformed.  3. solve the actual issue


I did a super quick mockup of what you might start with - note this is quick and probably can be reduced down to 1-2 lines of CSS instead but quick was my initial goal here https://jsfiddle.net/L3b61ezf/
